# How to leave a declared function undefined in C++ like with `undefined` in Haskell?

Tags: c++, haskell, undefined-function

In Haskell there is a constant called `undefined` that you can use to
declare a function without defining it (i.e. a function prototype with an empty body) as with `square`in

```
square :: Int -> Int   -- declaration
square = undefined     -- empty definition

main = putStrLn.show.square $ 3
```

This is tremendously useful to defer the work on `square` and focus on getting the `main` function right first, because the Haskell compiler makes sure that the whole file compiles as if `square` was defined.

The C++ equivalent is

```
#import <iostream>
int square(int x){
  //TODO incomplete
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << square(3);
}
```

My intention is to invoke a compiler like `clang++` as a typechecker for `main` alone and work on `square` later. Imagine that `square` really is one of many not-yet-defined complex functions that return a complex data structure with a non-trivial constructor. I would have to write a lot of code to create returnable objects just to get the functions to compile.

Is there something quick-and-dirty in C++ similar to `undefined`?

Comment: The linker is a step after compilation. Your code has passed the compiler's type checking already when you get that error.

Comment: Is there something you want to achieve here as this is a trivial example and your real world case can probably be solved without the need for this

Comment: A workaround is to compile a "mock" file where minimum functions are defined (std::cout/exception/assert).  You can put all the undefined functions there and remove while implementing.  Not as quick as the "undefined", but a bit more secure by not crashing unexpectedly.

Comment: I don't really see the use for this, you could just give it an empty definition for the time being, but if you want similar behavior (e.g. a crash), you could use a macro to define something like this: `#define UNDEFINED{_ASSERT(0)}`, and then use that after your function declaration, but as @EdChum mentioned, there is probably a better way to fix your actual problem

Comment: `undefined` is not something like a null pointer. One can implement `undefined = undefined`. So it is bascially a function that maps to itself.

Comment: `undefined` is not that useful with strict semantics. If you just want to avoid defining a function, give it a `{ throw "undefined"; }` body.

Comment: @xEric_xD one use for `undefined` is that the compiler will tell you what type it expects where you've used `undefined`, this is often very useful in calls like `someGenericLibraryFn (someAbstractHelper undefined) 42`  where the type signatures of the functions might be a bit long and you want to just see *that one part* of the type signature. I don't know if @mahene was hoping to get that feature from C++ though …

Comment: @unhammer that would be a nice plus, but is not my intention. I just want a "placeholder that will crash the program if you try to actually call it, but which compiles correctly and will be type-checked" (see Davislor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @molbdnilo.
Using `throw` is concise and works perfectly:

```
int square(int x) {
  throw("undefined");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use assert as following:

```
int square(int x) 
{
  assert(0);
}
```

This has the advantage that it can't be caught and will always fail. This will protect you better in case you forget to implement the function.

Comment: Uncatchability and protection against forgetting are two important points i totally missed. Thanks. In order to distinguish that assert from other "normal" asserts i [found out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3692961/4936725) that you can annotate an assert as in assert(0&&"undefined");

Comment: But i don't like that it's a C macro that appears to be disabled in release builds.

Answer (score 0):

C++ has pure `virtual` functions, for use in abstract base classes.

```
class foo {
  virtual void bar() = 0;
};
```

The function `foo::bar()` cannot be called, and indeed a `foo` object cannot even be created, but it can be overridden in a derived class of `foo`.  You can, however, give a definition for it that derived classes inherit by default.

Another thing in C++ that’s somewhat similar to `undefined` is an uninitialized function pointer.  A safer, more modern solution might be a lambda expression or `static` stub function that aborts the program.

The meaning of `undefined` in actual use is something like: a placeholder that will crash the program if you try to actually call it, but which compiles correctly and will be type-checked.  For individual object files, declaring an `extern` prototype for a function that isn’t defined anywhere will do the job.  If you’re linking the whole program, there has to be some kind of definition (although function pointers can get around that, at the cost of safety), but it can be a stub.

Comment: Good remark; that is conceptually quite different from Haskell's `undefined` though.

Comment: They’re very different languages.  I’ll expand on my answer a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Some alternatives are listed from most preferred to least preferred.
It really depends at what point you need your code not to work.

Compile time,

```
int square(int x) = delete;  // not implemented { ... }
```

```
[[deprecated("to be implemented")]] int square(int x) { ... }
```

(can be combined with other cases)

Link time,

```
int square(int x);  // not implemented { ... }
```

Runtime time,

```
[[noreturn]] int square(int x) { /*not implemented*/ }
```

(can be combined with others below)

```
int square(int x) { assert(0);  /*not implemented*/ }
```

(always test your code in debug mode)

```
int square(int x) { throw; }
```

(supposedly, throw with no argument triggers termination)

```
int square(int x) { throw your_private_unimplemented_class{}; }
```